# Does cooking game belong here under Hunting, or on the Cooking SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am wondering if I should post questions about cooking game here, or put it under the cooking SE?  For elk and venison, there are a few questions with answers there, but for duck and goose, it is hard to tell the wild from domestic questions.  I see utility in allowing the questions here under the hunting tag because it also is more likely to be seen by the relatively few people who eat wild game and less likely to be seen by those who might wish to discuss the ethics or aesthetics of eating game rather than the actual question.  All that said, it is cooking.  Any thoughts?

Comment: if you are cooking a duck or goose, does it matter if they are wild or domestic?

Comment: @James, yes, the difference is very significant between wild and domestic.  The fat content and variability of diet are two of the most divergent aspects.  I didn't realize it until a friend bought me a book on cooking wild ducks and geese and I found out that all the domestic recipes I had were way off the mark. (https://amzn.com/1607745291)

Comment: I think either is OK.  Mods on cooking would not allow is it to disintegrate into ethics or aesthetics of eating game rather than the actual question.

Answer (score 10):

I pretty much agree with both answers, but want to introduce an additional aspect, which is the complexity of the cooking.

If the OP is asking about elaborate recipes, with sauces and garnishes and/or the courses and wines that would best complement the game course, the question belongs on cooking.

If the OP is asking about how to simply or safely prepare, e.g., elk tartare, it belongs on TGO.  Similarly, if you have a lakeside cabin and want tips how to simply prepare the day's catch, it could be on TGO.

Answer (score 9):

Cooking game while outdoors (camping, backpacking, etc) = Outdoors
Cleaning/Dressing game taken while outdoors for later cooking = Outdoors

Cooking game in your home that happened to be obtained outdoors = Cooking

The last one is hard for me.  How to best cook [insert game] is a very common outdoors topic even though it is often cooked indoors.  However, I think while it isn't necessarily bad here, it is even better suited to Cooking.

Answer (score 4):

If you slaughter, cut up, and cook an animal while you're still somewhere in the jungle, it belongs on Outdoors.SE.

If a rented helicopter has kindly transferred the carcass of your freshly “harvested” moose to your truck/trailer and you've managed to put the carcass in the giant freezer of your luxury lakeside property, and you're presenting bits of it to guests three months later, it belongs on Cooking SE.

The reasoning here is that the indoor cooking food obtained outdoor is not an outdoor activity, nor is it preparation thereof, just like how editing photos obtained outdoor is not an outdoor activity.

Comment: I don't think that reasoning would work broadly.  For instance, I think it would be fine to ask a question about tent repair on Outdoors, even if you are doing it with a sewing machine at home.  Questions like this one would also be moved to cooking under that logic, but I think they belong in Outdoors: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/what-are-the-pro-and-cons-of-vacuum-sealed-vs-mylar-bags-for-diy-dehydrated-food (Dehydrated food question).

Comment: @David I don't agree with the tent analogy.  A tent is outdoor equipment: you're repairing your tent because you want to use it in the outdoors again.  The preparation at home of food collected outdoor does not need any outdoor skills or equipment.  A better analogy would be editing photos you took in the outdoor: it's related to the great outdoors, but it's not an outdoor question; it fits on Photography.

Comment: What about which bag to use for dehydrated food that you would take camping?  Do you think that fits?  I am honestly not sure which way this should go. I can see what your answer is (it should go to cooking unless you are cooking in the outdoors), but not the reasoning of why this is the proper answer.  Can you expand your answer with more of the thought process of why the division should be articulated that way?

Comment: I think there's a lot of innuendo and tone here that detracts from the point I think you're trying to make.  It is possible that your point is that it doesn't count when rich people do it in a way you wouldn't, but I don't think that's the point you were going for.  Nonetheless you've added it with the classist undertones.

Comment: Fair enough.  I personally think the innuendo is fairly mild and friendly.  I have observed only the helicopter-variant in the wild.